expo-camera not reading pdf417 on web
I am trying to scan pdf417 barcodes on a React web app but nothing is detected, QR codes are perfectly read. I can read pdf417 barcode with React native on Android with the same code.
Here is a snack
I intend for the pdf417 codes to be read on the web in the same way as it is done on React native on Android.
